# Calculate amount of elements in collection by property

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

I was given this task: Calculate amount of elements in collection by property: "name"

```
 let array = [
    {name: 'Serhii'},
    {name: 'Serhii'},
    {name: 'Nile'},
    {name: 'Apple'},
    {name: 'Serhii'},
    {name: 'Serhii'},
    {name: 'Apple'},
    {name: 'Serhii'},
];
```

Here is my solution:

```
 function calculateElements(property, arr) {
    let amount = {};

    arr.forEach((e) => {
        let p = e[property];
        p in amount ? amount[p]++ : amount[p] = 1;
    });
    return amount;
}
console.log(calculateElements('name', array));
```

Is there more efficient way to do it?

Comment: not bad but i'd rewrite with reduce instead of forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The function name should probably not be `calculateElements()` but rather something like `countDistinctValuesByProperty()` which has more specific meaning.
- I would suggest that what you are doing here is, in essence, a map-reduce problem and perhaps should leverage existing `Array` functionality for this.

For example:

```
function countDistinctValuesByProperty(prop, array) {
    return array.map(el => el[prop]);
                .reduce(
                    (counter, value) => {
                        return value in counter ?
                            counter[value]++ : counter[value] = 1;
                    }
                    , {});
}
```

Or in this simple case, we could probably just go straight to reduce:

```
function countDistinctValuesByProperty(prop, array) {
    return array.reduce(
       (counter, el) => {
           if (prop in el) {
               return el[prop] in counter ?
                   counter[el[prop]]++ : counter[el[prop]] = 1;
           }
           return counter;
       , {});
}
```

- This second solution is more optimal for this particular need, as it would operate in O(n) as opposed to O(2n) for the first.  I just show the first solution to prompt your thinking on how you might approach a scenario where you needed to perform more complex mapping logic on input array before being able to get to the reduce step.
- You do nothing to validate the parametric input on your function.  I would think you should validate the property name parameter as being non-zero-length string.  You also might consider validating that array is in-fact an Array object before trying to work with it.  In either case if validation fails, you can exit early.

Answer (score 2):

That looks quite fine to me. You can remove the parentheses around `e` in the arrow function.

If you're really going for efficiency, a [regular `for` loop is faster than the `.forEach()` method](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-loop). That can help if you have a very large amount of objects to process and need to display a result instantly to a user, but otherwise the optimization is unnecessary for what you're trying to accomplish.